# Is there a needed GHC option for an executable using the FFI?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ffi, ghci, haskell-stack

I have a module `Main` in `Main.hs`. The program uses the FFI (in particular, `FunPtr`).

When I run `stack exec ghci` and I load the module (`:l src/Main.hs`), it works perfectly.

However when I compile the module to an executable and I run the executable, I get a crash, namely a segmentation fault.

Therefore I'm wondering whether I need to compile with a certain option. Is there a specific option to use when dealing with the FFI ? I tried `-O0`, `-fllvm`, no way. Maybe `stack exec ghci` includes an option that could be used with GHC ?

Also, is there a debug option that one can set to GHC in order to run the executable with `gdb` ? I tried the `-g` option but `gdb` does not find debugging symbols. **EDIT** This point is solved: `gdb` finds debugging symbols when I compile with `stack exec -- ghc -g -rtsopts src/Main.hs`.

I'm on Linux Ubuntu and I'm using GHC 8.2.2.

## EDIT

Here is a minimal program that reflects the structure of my real program. This one works fine (in GHCI or as an executable), but I include it nevertheless.

*helloffi.c*:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

double** evalf(double (*f)(double), double x){
    double** out = malloc(2 * sizeof(double*));
    for(unsigned i=0; i<2; i++){
        out[i] = malloc(2 * sizeof(double));
        out[i][0] = (*f)(x);
        out[i][1] = (*f)(x+1);
    }
    return out;
}

double sumpointer(double** pptr){
    double x=0;
    for(unsigned i=0; i<2; i++){
        for(unsigned j=0; j<2; j++){
            x += pptr[i][j];
        }
    }
    return x;
}
```

*main module of the library, Lib.hs*

```
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Lib
  where
import           Foreign.C.Types       
import           Foreign.Ptr           (Ptr, FunPtr, freeHaskellFunPtr)

type CFunction = CDouble -> IO CDouble

foreign import ccall "wrapper" functionPtr 
    :: CFunction -> IO (FunPtr CFunction)

foreign import ccall "evalf" c_evalf
    :: FunPtr CFunction
    -> CDouble
    -> IO (Ptr (Ptr CDouble))

fun2cfun :: (Double -> Double) -> CFunction
fun2cfun f x = 
    return $ realToFrac (f (realToFrac x))

evalFun :: (Double -> Double) -> Double -> IO (Ptr (Ptr CDouble))
evalFun f x = do
    fPtr <- functionPtr (fun2cfun f)
    result <- c_evalf fPtr (realToFrac x)
    freeHaskellFunPtr fPtr
    return result

foreign import ccall "sumpointer" c_sumpointer
    :: Ptr (Ptr CDouble) -> IO CDouble
```

*module Main.hs, to be compiled*

```
module Main
  where
import           Lib

main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- evalFun (\x -> x*x) 2
    y <- c_sumpointer x
    print y
```

Comment: Could you post the code that's causing this problem? I think that would also be helpful.

Comment: @AJFarmar I don't know how to minimize. There are 1000 lines of C code. Maybe the only thing I could do is to summarize the structure of the program ?

Comment: I see, this makes finding a specific issue very hard. I'm not sure the general structure would help.

Comment: Try making a "Hello World" type of program using FFI, and see if it works. We don't need a 1000 line program if the issue is in the compilation process and not the code.

Comment: @4castle Ok, I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: @4castle Done. The helloworld works.

Comment: I will try to complicate the helloworld now. My real program passes pointers through the FFI. I will include pointers.

Comment: It works too :-(

Comment: @4castle The helloworld works but I have included it in my post nevertheless.

Comment: It's become clear that the problem is not with how you're compiling your program, but rather with how you're using the FFI (or perhaps something entirely different in your C or Haskell code). It's not likely to be possible to answer this without seeing code. You might want to try `printf`/`trace` debugging, GDB, etc.

Comment: It looks as if you are causing _undefined behavior_ on the C side, e.g. by using some pointer to access unallocated (or freed) memory. In C land, UB does not mean "crash for sure". The program may or may not crash depending on how much memory is allocated, or where it is allocated, etc. It might be the case that under GHCi the allocation is done in a way that case the program to incidentally work, while under GHC that does not happen. This a common "C pointer hell" problem, since it usually very hard to understand what went wrong and where :-(

Comment: What happened when debugging in gdb?

Comment: @Euge I get a series of pointer adresses `0x000...`, I don't know what to do with that.

Comment: @chi Thanks for you comment. I have a C function which generates a pointer and an integer which represents the "length" of the pointer (sorry for the wording if it is unappropriate). The integer is obtained by passing `&i` to the function, and the function calculates `*i`. And then, when I run the executable, I get the pointer adress `0x00000000000000000` and a huge integer (whereas the good integer should be `168` for this example).

Comment: @chi Also when I run an example in C only (without Haskell), this works fine. And when I run `stack ghci` (not `stack exec ghci`), that doesn't work.

Comment: Are you using malloc to get `i`? And malloc returns `0x00`? Can you post that piece of code?

Comment: @Euge No, this is not the pointer to `i`. I type `int i;` then I run a function `f(...., &i)`. There's no `malloc` for `i`. The pointer is the output of `f`. My code is [on github](https://github.com/stla/opengl-implicit3) if you want to take a look. The function which causes a problem (`f`) is `computeContour3d` in `C/marchingcubes.c`.

Comment: Ok, I see no error in that piece of code. I would try to call `malloc` for `i` (`ntriangles`) to see what happens, but it should work as it is anyway...

Comment: @Euge I have half-solved the problem. The code in `C/marchingcubes.c` does not correctly read the entries of the arrays defined in `C/tables.c`. So I've moved these arrays in `C/marchingcubes.c`, it's better but there's still one issue.

Comment: @Euge it works !!!!!!!!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'm glad :) You can post the answer if it's clear enough and you consider it might be helpful for others

Comment: @Euge I will try to do a minimal example. I'll post an answer if it reproduces the issue. But not today, it's late.

Comment: @Euge Problem reproduced with a minimal example. Please take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this is not really an answer to the question but I have painfully solved the issue and I think it might be helpful for others. It is worth to share. So I post a minimal example showing the problem. A very minimal example.

```
helloffi/
├── C
│   ├── array.c
│   ├── helloffi.c
│   └── helloffi.h
├── helloffi.cabal
├── Setup.hs
├── src
│   ├── Lib.hs
│   └── Main.hs
└── stack.yaml
```

*array.c*: define an array in a C file, for example:

```c
int array[2][3] =  
    {{1, 24, 1},
     {2, 19, 1}};
```

*helloffi.c*: define a function that uses this array, for example:

```c
#include "helloffi.h"

int getCoef(unsigned i, unsigned j){
    return array[i][j];
}
```

*helloffi.h*, the header file:

```c
int array[2][3];
int getCoef(unsigned, unsigned);
```

That's all for the C part. Now the Haskell part. Make a library module importing the C function.

*Lib.hs*:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}
module Lib
  where
import           Foreign.C.Types       

foreign import ccall "getCoef" c_getCoef
    :: CUInt -> CUInt -> IO CInt
```

*Main.hs*, to be compiled to an executable:

```hs
module Main
  where
import           Lib

main :: IO ()
main = do
    x <- c_getCoef 0 1
    print x
```

That's all. And now, the mystery. Compile the library (to get the module `Lib` and the executable generated from `Main.hs`, let's say this one is called `test`).

`stack exec ghci`, gives the correct result (`24`):

```
Prelude> :l src/Main.hs 
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( src/Main.hs, interpreted )
Ok, one module loaded.
*Main> main
24
```

*run the executable*, gives a wrong result (always `0`):

```
$ .stack-work/install/x86_64-linux/lts-11.4/8.2.2/bin/test 
0
```

The `test` executable is the compiled `Main.hs`. However it does not correctly read the entries of the array in `array.c`, while `:l src/Main.hs` after `stack exec ghci` gives the correct result.

Isn't it weird ? Does anyone has an explanation ?

## Solution

I don't know yet why the behavior differs between `stack exec ghci` and the executable but now one has a solution thanks to @Alec's comments below: it suffices to replace `int array[2][3]` in the header file with `extern int array[2][3]`. It looks like the executable considers `int array[2][3]` as the definition of `array`, whose entries are initialized to `0`, while `stack exec ghci` considers it as the declaration of `array`.

Comment: What happens if you replace `int array[2][3];` in your header file with `extern int array[2][3];`? I suspect GHC/Stack may be linking/compiling stuff in such an order that the `int array[2][3];` in the header (which is a tentative definition) ends up being considered as the definition (and not the declaration) of `array`.

Comment: @Alec You are right!! It works if I do that. Thanks!

Comment: @Alec Do you want to write this as an answer ? Otherwise I could include this in my post (giving the credit to you of course).

Comment: Haha, just include it in your post - the problem is the tentative definition of `array`. That only makes sense based on the stuff you just posted, so it is probably simpler to update your answer. Glad to have helped.